# Connect Databricks cluster with local machine (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, databricks

I want to connect to Databricks cluster (AWS) from my local machine but I want to execute the entire code in the cluster. With Databricks Connect only the spark code is executed in the cluster. I'm looking for alternative solution. SSH interpreter or something similar to that. I work with PyCharm (IDE).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with such a approach (but you need to write small script for your IDE):

- you commit to some brunch in git (like staging)
- your IDE executes databricks cli command "databricks repos update" which will perform pull
- your IDE executes databricks cli job command to run notebook from repo

Databricks cli can be executed as a Rest Api, bash/cmd or can be imported as sdk to programming language

Comment: I want to use that for local tests I don't what to execute my code when I commit.

Comment: Or maybe I can't really understand what do you want to say.

Comment: But you wrote that you want to execute it directly on databricks with some development branch in repos it is possible

Comment: I want to develop jobs in my IDE and I want to execute them locally

Comment: databricks is cloud environment so fully locally is no way....

Comment: There is no way to execute Python code in the cluster from my local machine? I thought there is a way to use SSH interpreter!

Comment: I know only databricks-connect or via api/cli/sdk